# Creating the new Zip file every time using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

The following Python script creates the zip file of the given directory. However, when I run the script new zip should be created. The name of the new zip file should be the current date and time. What modification needs to be done in the following script. Please guide me or help to modify the script. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("D:\data_2"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        print("operation completed")
zf.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated?